# IE6, Absolute Position, 100% Width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Another problem with IE6..
It's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            <span style="display:block; background:yellow; height: 170px; width:100%;"></span>
            <div class="d">
Hello World!            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a{
    background: black;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    width: 200px;
}

.b{
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

.c{
    position: relative;
}

.d{
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
}

.e{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

([live demo on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Acp5V/7/)).

Check it in modern browsers and IE6. You see something like that:

[image: fiddle in IE6]

How to fix it?

Comment: @Diodeus: No, I have tested on an original IE6 on Win XP SP2

Comment: is it a problem with width or with positioning at the bottom?

Comment: @simoncereska: I think it's positioning...

Comment: You may need to go to the ugly IE "expression" method. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064865/ie6-absolute-positioning

Comment: @Diodeus: I hate expressions.. if i found no working answers, I'll go with conditions..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">

            <span style="display:block; background:yellow; height: 170px; width:100%;"></span>
            <div class="d">
Hello World!            </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width: 15px 10px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.d{
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.e{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the black square should be a div, not a border... (because I want to set a image background)